# How to change game speed in mid development without touching the Timescale in Unity (2D)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a game similar to Sand balls and I was wondering how can I speed up the game a bit without touching the timescale? A nice and somehow correct approach would be to scale down all my objects so gravity can also "affect" the drop movement. I already tested that and works as expected, except I have to apply that for 100+ levels... and would break some prefabs (a mass level editor to scale by bounding box would work but that's another story)
On the other hand, I have timescale but feels like it's the incorrect approach since it also affects animations and leads to unwanted behaviors.

So... do you know any other ways to speed up the game?

Comment: Why do you tag this question `performance`? I guess by speed up you don't refer to execution performance/efficiency, right? In general I'd say this is a bit broad .. it depends a lot on your project and how `speed` is defined in your objects .. e.g. if stuff is falling down you could increase the gravity and all applied forces ..

Comment: Lol, I think it was by mistake. I tried to add the timescale tag but it didn't let me do that because my reputation is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If objects is falling **down**, you can increase gravity. Or without touching timescale, you can just create a public speed multiplier variable and set it to **1** at start.

If you only move balls (Assumed from give sand balls reference), just multiply speed variable of ball with public speed multiplier variable. When you want to change the speed, just change the variable. As an example:

```
var ballSpeed = baseBallSpeed * speedMultiplier;
```